# Read long xml with php

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

i have a problem with reading my xml. By code down i read xml, bud how i say at the end of this post, i need read subelements. But i don't know how.

```
   $reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open("data/sns.xml");
while($reader->read()){ 
    if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == "item" && $reader->getAttribute('sensor') == "th0" && $reader->getAttribute('cat') == "temp" && $reader->getAttribute('unit') == "c") {
                        echo "Venkovní teplota: ".$reader->readString()." °C";
                        echo "<br />";
                    }
                    if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == "item" && $reader->getAttribute("sensor") == "th0" && $reader->getAttribute("cat") == "hum" && $reader->getAttribute("unit") == "rel"){
                        echo "venkovní vlhkost: ".$reader->readString();
                        echo "<br />";
                    }}
```

I can read this, but my xml looks like:

```
 <data timeframe="actual">
<item sensor="system" cat="version" unit="text">4.9u</item>
<item sensor="system" cat="version" unit="num">49</item>
<item sensor="system" cat="build" unit="num">1261</item>
<item sensor="system" cat="platform" unit="text">SilverStone_DC01</item>
<item sensor="system" cat="language" unit="text">Czech</item>
<item sensor="system" cat="temp" unit="unit">c</item>
<item sensor="system" cat="hum" unit="unit">rel</item>
<item sensor="system" cat="press" unit="unit">hpa</item>
<item sensor="system" cat="wind" unit="unit">ms</item>
<item sensor="system" cat="rain" unit="unit">mm</item>
<item sensor="date0" cat="date" unit="utc">20160111090606</item>
<item sensor="date0" cat="date2" unit="utc">11.01.2016 09:06:06</item>
<item sensor="date0" cat="puredate" unit="utc">11.01.2016</item>
<item sensor="date0" cat="time" unit="utc">09:06:06</item>
<item sensor="date0" cat="year" unit="utc">2016</item>
<item sensor="date0" cat="month" unit="utc">01</item>
<item sensor="date0" cat="day" unit="utc">11</item>
<item sensor="date0" cat="dayofweek" unit="utc">1</item>
<item sensor="date0" cat="hour" unit="utc">09</item>
<item sensor="date0" cat="min" unit="utc">06</item>
<item sensor="date0" cat="sec" unit="utc">06</item>
<item sensor="date0" cat="date" unit="local">20160111100606</item>
<item sensor="date0" cat="date2" unit="local">11.01.2016 10:06:06</item>
<item sensor="date0" cat="puredate" unit="local">11.01.2016</item>
<item sensor="date0" cat="time" unit="local">10:06:06</item>
<item sensor="date0" cat="year" unit="local">2016</item>
<item sensor="date0" cat="month" unit="local">01</item>
<item sensor="date0" cat="day" unit="local">11</item>
</data>
```

and i need read for example. sensor: date0 and cat: date2 and unit: utc and now show me a string.

When you are looking for this code u say it is easy, but in my xml i have next tag

```
<data timeframe="lastday"></data>
```

and the same items, bud i need to read only actual.

Please help.

Thank You

Comment: read the XMLReader manual. learn how to read attributes (timeframe is an attribute). rewrite your code. test it. then come back with specific questions. have fun.

Answer (score 1):

Make yourself familiar with [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php), with these your task is very simple:

```
<?php
$string = __your_xml_string_here;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$sensors = $xml->xpath("//item[@sensor='date0']");
print_r($sensors);
# or loop over them with foreach
foreach ($sensors as $sensor) {
    // do sth. useful here
    // the full string can be obtained with
    // $sensor->asXML() or $sensor->__toString()
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is little helped.

But when i "cut" that xml how i want with your code. It is returns some understandtible, if you know what i mean.

`Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [timeframe] => actual ) [item] => Array ( [0] => 4.9u [1] => 49 [2] => 1261 [3] => SilverStone_DC01 [4] => Czech [5] => c [6] => rel [7] => hpa [8] => ms [9] => mm [10` ...

And i need to write out only for example:
<item sensor="system" cat="temp" unit="unit">c</item> and 
<item sensor="date0" cat="date2" unit="utc">11.01.2016 09:06:06</item>

Comment: @HonzaRulc: Honestly, I do not understand what you mean. What exactly is your desired output? If you want to have the string as output, look into the updated answer again (at the bottom).

Comment: OP is using XMLReader, isn't he.

Comment: No. XMLReader is harder. But i found a reason.
`$xml->xpath("//data[@timeframe='actual']/item[@sensor='sunset'][@cat='standard'][@unit='local']");`
This is it. Thank you all for help.